# Weird function __Boxed<int> for boxing and unboxing after decompiling

Tags: c#, boxing

Hello I'm having some issues trying to find a replacement to this portion of code after decompiling an executable.

I can't seem to find a replacement in c# for __Boxed anywhere online

```
        DateTime startTime = dev.runningList[0].startTime;
        // ISSUE: variable of a boxed type
        __Boxed<int> day = (System.ValueType) startTime.Day;
        objArray2[0] = (object) day;
        object[] objArray3 = objArray1;
```

Comment: what are you using to decode, what is the objective, and where is the original source code?

Comment: I'm using jetbrains dot peek, the original source was gone with one of our ex employees

Comment: Don't make dotPeek your only decompiler, also see what ILSpy tells you.

Comment: I'll give it a try man thanks! @HansPassant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is boxing the integer value of `startTime.Day` into an object.  The reason you are seeing `__Boxed<T>` is probably a feature of the decompilation tool you are using.

When you need to use a value type as an object, the compiler will box it in order that it is treated as an object (heap based) as opposed to a value type (stack based).

For your own code you don't need to box the int, you could just write this:

```
DateTime startTime = dev.runningList[0].startTime;
int day = startTime.Day;
objArray2[0] = day;
```

When compiling this to IL, `day` will be boxed by the compiler as needed - you do not need to manually box it.